# How to merge Hyperopt and Sacred together?

Tags: pytorch, hyperopt, python-sacred

I am trying to use omniboard to keep a track of all the experiments hyperopt library is doing. The link below is from sacred library documentation and I am not able to use it to merge hyperopt and sacred together. Right now when I am defining an objective function and putting it in fmin(), I am getting a TypeError saying 'NoneType object is not callable'. Can somebody please help me figure out a way around this.

https://github.com/yuvalatzmon/SACRED_HyperOpt_v2